# Tornado take full CPU usage and concurrent is not acceptable

Tags: python, linux, http, web, tornado

Code is very simple, this basic usage of Tornado:

```
class JustHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('just get.')

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/just", JustHandler),
])
application.listen(7777)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And I wrote a simple client to send requests:

```
class Request:
    def GetEmpty(self):
        try:
            req  = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:7777/just')
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout = 15)
            file = resp.read()
            print 'Get empty'
        except Exception,e:
            print str(e)

def ReqThread():
    req = Request()
    while True:
        req.GetEmpty()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'start.'
    threads = []
    for i in range(0, 100):
        thread = threading.Thread(target = ReqThread)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    print 'end.'
```

As you see, I open 100 threads, each thread with loop request without end, then check CPU usage of tornado, it goes 100%.

If I try to increase threads count, some request will fail with timeout.

What am I wrong? Tornado should accept high requsets at a same time.

My system is Ubuntu 14.04, Tornado version is 4.2.1, CPU is E3 1231 v3.

Comment: Tornado 4.3, python 2.7.9 `siege --concurrent=1000 --reps 2  http://127.0.0.1:7777/just`   239.52 trans/sec, Availability:        100.00 %, Fedora 21.  Without any fd and tcp tune

Comment: Your client code is running without a problems, 100% success req.

Comment: I tried siege, got same result as yours.

Comment: But If I use my simple requst client, and open multi instance, it will timeout after a while.

Comment: More test with siege, if set reps to 20, you can see the CPU usage of tornado goes to 100%, and concurrency in siege result is 272, the concurrency is too low. If increase reps more larger, timeout will happen. Or my test way is not correct? How to test concurrency in tornado, official said it can handle tens of thousands of open connections.

Comment: I run it without a problem. CPU usage <50%, VM 1vcpu, ubuntu 12.04. And of course open connection is not the same as open/close one

Comment: Could you please give me your siege result with `siege --concurrent=1000 --reps 100 http://127.0.0.1:7777/just`

Comment: I run siege with reps 100 cost 200 seconds, that means tornado only can handle 500 requests in 1 second, how about yours? Is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any wait time in your code, indeed you get 100% CPU usage. You are issuing and serving as much request as your CPU can handle.

You could add time.sleep(1) in the loop after req.GetEmpty() getting about 100 req/s for 100 threads (you'll actually get less but you can tune this).

Comment: Yes, I don't have any wait time in my request client, I want to use this to test my tornado server, the request client only take a few CPU usage, instead, the tornado server take 100% CPU usage.

Comment: @user2735005 if you want to test your tornado server performance, try command `ab`. I copy your code and test it with `ab -n 100000 -c 1024 http://192.168.1.116:7777/just`, and monitor CPU with *htop*, nothing went wrong.